# How to create a new column which is less than the previous column value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sample

I am trying to create a new column which is formed by taking the value from column A as the upper bound of the sample which I would like to take. I tried the following but no avail. Any suggestions? Suppose the value A is 15.25, then I would like to generate a value which is between 1 and 15.25 which are spaced by 1/4.

```r
my_data = data.frame(A = sample(seq(1, 20, 1/4), 10))
my_data %>% mutate(B = sample(seq(1, A, 1/4), 1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rowwise` that

> allows you to compute on a data frame a row-at-a-time

as follows. Otherwise it would take the entire `A` column into sample where you need to specify only 1 value as upper-bound:

```
my_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(B = sample(seq(1, A, 1/4), size = 1))

# A tibble: 10 × 2
# Rowwise: 
       A     B
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 19     9.25
 2  8     6.25
 3  7.25  1.5 
 4  3.25  2.75
 5  2.75  2.25
 6 11     4   
 7 14.8  13   
 8  9.25  7.75
 9 10     9   
10 10.5   8.25
```

Comment: Very interesting. I could not think of ```rowwise()```. Can u explain why ```rowwise()``` is used here.

Comment: As I specified in the answer. You only need to put 1 value of `A` into `seq` to generate the sequence of equally spaced numbers. `rowwise` make sure that you mutate the data set row by row, taking one value of `A` into each iteration. Whereas without `rowwise`, `A` in `seq` is the whole column `A` and not just 1 value.

Comment: :-). Back again!

Comment: Hahaha yes, how are you doing my friend? I am trying to challenge myself to python questions, but sometimes I fall back to my comfort zone :)

Comment: No difference between these two. Is there any specific occassion we need to use ```rowwise()``` specifically. ```mtcars %>% mutate(x = hp*2)```
```mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(x = hp*2)```

Comment: Yes that's true. Because in both of these 2 code chunks you would like to multiply `hp` by 2. So whether you multiply the whole `hp` vector at once or do it one by one (which is slower) does not lead to a different result. But in your question every value for `A` needs to be considered separately in your `seq` and `sample` operations.

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution:

```
set.seed(11) # for reproducibility
my_data <- data.frame(A = sample(seq(1, 20, 1/4), 10))

my_data$B <- sapply(my_data$A, \(x) sample(seq(1, x, 1/4), 1))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > my_data
>        A     B
> 1   9.25  9.25
> 2  14.75 13.00
> 3   7.00  2.75
> 4   4.75  4.50
> 5  10.00  2.25
> 6  15.75 12.25
> 7   3.75  1.50
> 8  16.25  9.50
> 9   9.50  5.25
> 10 10.50  3.75
> ```